# Instagram API Access Token Request Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, instagram, instagram-api

Hello I have tried to use the **instagram api** to get a connection token. I first tested it on postman and this is what I did:
I used this link to make a request post to the instagram api:

`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=clientid&client_secret=clientsecret&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://mysite/&code=thecode`

The api gives me an error: `Missing required field client_id`

But when I set the content type to **x-www-form-urlencoded** everything works fine on postman.

So I tried to do the same thing in javascript with the node module **request**. I tried to do the same thing as on postman with the module but it does not work... Here is my code:

```
request(`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=clientid&client_secret=clientsecret&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://mysite/&code=` + code, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log('body:', body)
    })
```

Comment: There must be other params in the header (in postman). Did you check that?

Comment: This is all the postman headers Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: <calculated when request is sent> Host: <calculated when request is sent> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0 Accept: / Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Connection: keep-alive

Answer (score 0):

As per MDN, the content type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Update:
You should read the node doc : https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs

**Get method:**

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'api.instagram.com',
  path: '/oauth/access_token?client_id=clientid&client_secret=clientsecret&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://mysite/&code=thecode',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "Accept": "Accept-Encoding"
  }
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  // ...
});
```

**Post method:**

```
var headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Accept": "Accept-Encoding"
};

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers
};

var form = {
  grant_type:'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
  client_id: 'id',
  client_secret: 'secret'
  redirect_uri : 'https://mysite/&code=thecode'
};

var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
  // do stuff
});

request.write(querystring.stringify(form));
request.end();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Comment: You must have tried the GET method. I removed the PORT part. ECONNREFUSED usually get when you try to connect to a wrong port.

Comment: The post pseudocode is wrong. What is "querystring"? Lack code attr in the form.